# Windows 7 Printer driver not installed

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, network-printer, print-drivers

Im running windows 7 32 bit, trying to install a driver and i get an error saying " Printer driver was not installed. Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000001e).

Comment: Have you tried googling the error code??

Comment: It will be very helpful if you [edit] your question to include some details about the printer you're trying to install. We can not possibly help you determine what's wrong with so little information.

Answer (score -1):

Causes of this error code are:

- There is insufficient disk space on the drive on which you installed Windows.
- There is an outdated or incompatible third-party driver (or drivers) installed on your computer -- for example a faulty video driver.
- There are system BIOS incompatibilities.

Some known methods of fixing this error are as follows:

- Method 1: Free Up Disk Space
- Method 2: Disable or Remove the Third-Party Driver

If the STOP 0x1E error message lists a driver by name, disable or remove that driver. If this resolves the issue, contact the hardware manufacturer for more information about how to obtain the latest version of the driver.

- Method 3: Upgrade Your System BIOS

Comment: About as useful as microsoft technet answers team.  Generic, irrelevant, rubbish answer.